# Why tabs not working when using mobile view (media queries)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My tabs don't seem to be working when it gets to mobile view. It works normally when the media queries are not activated. But once it get to mobile, it doesn't work.

I think it has something to do with using div.main. The red colour is what I want which is why I used div.main for media queries, however the tabs don't work.

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }

  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 0.4fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 10% 10% 10% 10% 10% 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 0px 0px;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-template-areas:
    "header header header header header header"
    "main main main text text download"
    "main main main lion lion download"
    "main main main select select download"
    "main main main color color download"
    "main main main deselect deselect download";
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .grid-container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-template-areas:
      "header"
      "main"
      "text"
      "lion"
      "select"
      "color"
      "deselect"
      "download";
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  div.main {
    background-color: red;
    /* padding: 0; */
    margin: 0;
    height: 400px;
    width: auto;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  #background-image {
    padding-top: 180px;
    padding-left: 100px;
    margin: 0;
    height: 400px;
    width: auto;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  #product-svg {
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    padding-left: 100px;
    margin: 0;
    height: 400px;
    width: auto;
  }
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  /* background-color: red; */
  margin: 50px;
}

.logo {
  position: fixed;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 13px;
  top: 15px;
}

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 47px;
  right: 13px;
  font-family: "Khula", sans-serif;
  line-height: 38px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.nav-link {
  margin: 18px;
  color: #222222;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.main {
  grid-area: main;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  margin: 18px;
}

.text {
  grid-area: text;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-top: 18px;
  margin-right: 18px;
}

.lion {
  grid-area: lion;
  background-color: orange;
  margin-right: 18px;
}

.color {
  grid-area: color;
  background-color: green;
  margin-right: 18px;
}

.download {
  grid-area: download;
  background-color: pink;
  margin-top: 18px;
  margin-right: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
}

.select {
  grid-area: select;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  margin-right: 18px;
}

.deselect {
  grid-area: deselect;
  background-color: grey;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
  margin-right: 18px;
}

.tab {
  float: left;

  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
.tab button {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: inherit;
  color: black;

  border: none;
  outline: none;

  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.tabcontent {
  float: left;
  padding: 0px 12px;
  border-left: none;
}

#product-svg {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50%;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}

#background-image {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 685px;
}

path {
  fill: #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">

  <div class="header">
    <img class="logo" src="logo.png" alt="">

    <nav class="navbar">
      <a href=about.html class="nav-link">About</a>
      <a href=contact.html class="nav-link">Contact</a>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <div class="main">

    <div id="London" class="tabcontent">
      <div id="container">
        <svg id="product-svg" viewBox="0 0 550 678">

        </svg>
        <img id="background-image" src="l7008.png" alt="">
      </div>

    </div>

    <div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>Paris</h3>
      <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>Tokyo</h3>
      <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text">c</div>
  <div class="lion">
    <div class="tab">
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')" id="defaultOpen">London</button>

      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="download">f</div>

  <div class="select">j</div>
  <div class="deselect">k</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your media query update this part
or change the max-with from 1200px to 600px (you may need to change again this 600px  for different type of mobile)

and i suggest you to read more about it here
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
#product-svg {
padding-bottom: 100px;
padding-left: 100px;
margin: 0;
height: 400px;
width: auto;


 }
```

Comment: @luck8  its working and thats why i already mentioned change that media query (max-width: 1200 to max-width: 600px)  Now i want to ask you again to change it to (max-width:200px).

Comment: the media query is working - but the tabs are not working - try and click on the tabs when below 600px

Comment: again change that 600px to 100px thats it.

Answer (score 0):

It was a bit difficult to understand what was happening without having access to your assets, but it looks like your SVG size in your media query is covering the buttons.
You can try either:

1. Decreasing the height of the SVG in the media query.
2. Rearranging the layout so the buttons aren't covered.

I made the SVG element green so it's easy to see what's happening and included some comments explaining it below.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  #product-svg {
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    padding-left: 100px;
    margin: 0;
    /* SVG size is covering buttons */
    height: 400px;
    width: auto;
  }
}

/* You haven't set size properties for the default here 
so the SVG isn't large enough to block buttons 
(it currently has a size of 0 and is not visible) */
#product-svg {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: green;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50%;
  /* I temporarily commented out your mix-blend-mode so it's easier to see what's 
  happening */
  /* mix-blend-mode: multiply; */
}
```